# Распарсить sql script

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, sql

Все доброго времени суток.
Есть `sql script`

```
/* Insert TESTTABLE1 */
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE1
(
  ID_TESTTABLE1          NUMBER (18) NOT NULL,
  TESTTABLE_VALUE1       NUMBER (18),
  TESTTABLE_KEY1       NUMBER (18)
);

/* Insert TESTTABLE */
 CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE
(
  ID_TESTTABLE          NUMBER (18) NOT NULL,
  TESTTABLE_VALUE      NUMBER (18),
  TESTTABLE_KEY      NUMBER (18)
);
```

Мне нужно распарсить, чтобы в итоге получился массив,

```
"/* Insert TESTTABLE1 */" ,"CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE1(ID_TESTTABLE1 NUMBER (18) NOT NULL,TESTTABLE_VALUE1 NUMBER (18),TESTTABLE_KEY1 NUMBER (18));", "/* Insert TESTTABLE */"
```

Что вы посоветовали? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

P.S.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("/*\w*/");
string[] substrings = regex.Split(sqlScript);
```

с регулярками работал мало, поэтому пока не очень получается.

Comment: то есть, в файле есть несколько sql выражений и комментариев. Нужно сделать массив выражений и комментариев?

Comment: угу согласен спасибо.

Comment: KoVadim да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
Match result = new Regex(@"(\w.*?;)|(/\*.*?\*/)", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline).Match(File.ReadAllText("somesqlscript.sql"));

while (result.Success) {
    // удаляем переносы и заменяем повторяющиеся пробелы
    resultList.Add(
        Regex.Replace(result.Value.Replace("\r\n", "").Trim(), "[ ]{2,}", " "));

    result = result.NextMatch();
}

// resultList содержит список получившихся подстрок
```

Вполне возможно что это решит поставленную задачу.

---

Посоветовал бы книжку про регулярки (которая с совой), в частности 9 главу.

Comment: У меня подозрение, что ваше регулярное выражение неправильно поймёт точку с запятой в комментарии или в строке.

Comment: спасибо. да она весит в закладках но все не как не займусь.
(\w.*?;)-это sql(любая буква и в конце ;) |(или) (/\*.*?\*/)-для комментария, правильно?

Comment: VladD та нет все работает;

Comment: @AndereyMaybe: Попробуйте для начала так: `CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE1 /* ляляля; тополя */ ( ID_TESTTABLE1 NUMBER (18) NOT NULL );`.

Answer (score 4):

На PHP ответ.
Много кода смотреть [здесь](http://ideone.com/8x4TxY).
Пример использования:

```
parse($sqlQuery);
```

Исходные данные:

```
/* " */ insert into table t values ("\"", "--", "/*"); /* -- */
DROP DATABASE; -- yes!
```

Результат:

```
{
    "comments": {
        "/* \" */",
        "/* -- */",
        "-- yes!"
    },
    "queryes": {
        " insert into table t values (\"\\\"\", \"--\", \"/*\");",
        "DROP DATABASE;"
    }
}
```

Если решите применить и найдете неправильно парсимые образцы запросов- пишите в комменты.

Comment: Ух! Кстати, полезные подвыражения: комментарий и строка, наверняка пригодятся в будущем.

+1.

Comment: @VladD поправил кстати шаблон строки. Тот на скорую руку написал не совсем корректно его.

Comment: @ReinRaus: переделал пример, чтобы читало из stdin: http://ideone.com/nOUDKN. Вроде работает :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: нашёл пример: http://ideone.com/nOUDKN#li_BtJwvA (#5).

Answer (score 2):

Вот [это обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589096/276994) подсказывает, что парсеры SQL не очень доступны бесплатно.

Если вам нужно *только* разбиение на команды, попробуйте сканировать до точки с запятой, игнорируя комментарии и строки (важно!). Должно быть что-то наподобие такого:

```
foreach (char c in input)
{
    outputBuffer.Append(c);
    switch (state)
    {
    case State.Normal:
        switch (c)
        {
        case '/':
            state = State.AfterSlash;
            break;
        case '-':
            state = State.AfterMinus;
            break;
        case '"':
            state = State.InString;
            break;
        case ';':
            yield return outputBuffer.ToString();
            outputBuffer.Clear();
        }
        break;
    case State.AfterSlash:
        state = (c == '*') ? State.InMultilineComment : State.Normal;
        break;
    case State.AfterMinus:
        state = (c == '-') ? State.InSinglelineComment : State.Normal;
        break;
    case State.InString:
        switch (c)
        {
            case '"':
                state = State.Normal;
                break;
            case '\\':
                state = State.InStringEscape;
                break;
        }
    // ну и так далее
    }
}
```

С другой стороны, если вы разрабатываете для бизнеса, пусть купят вам настоящий парсер, [12 тысяч долларов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589108/276994) реально не так уж много для нормальной компании.

Comment: @ReinRaus: сможете распарсить на регулярках? проблема: незакрытый комментарий в строке и незакрытая строка в комментарии. (Я имею в виду не конкретный текст от ТС, а произвольный правильный SQL.)

Comment: @VladD - скорее всего это возможно, но я не знаю в совершенстве все нюансы формата SQL, поэтому приведите пример какого-нибудь сложного в отношении парсинга SQL запроса, думаю выделить отдельные команды не трудно, а вот полный синтаксический анализ- дело потруднее :)  
P.S. Не могу найти RFC на SQL - наверно отчасти поэтому нет бесплатных парсеров :)  
P.P.S Не нашел, потому что ISO, а не RFC. Глаза мои округлились когда увидел, что pdf со стандартом стоит 200$ примерно. Думал стандарты бесплатны. Розовые очки упали с моих глаз :(

Comment: @ReinRaus: я не имел в виду полный парсер, он очень сложен (сам писал когда-то на lex/yacc). Я имел в виду разбор на statement'ы. По идее, statement ограничивается символом ';', если он не находится внутри строки или комментария. Строки заключаются в двойные кавычки, в них возможен escape-символ '\'. Комментарии бывают вида `/* ... */` (многострочные) или `--` (до конца текущей строки). Сложный текст:

    /* " */ insert into table t values ("\"", "--", "/*"); /* -- */

Comment: @VladD, А в комментариях возможно экранирование ?  
Например  

    /* text \*/ next text */

Comment: @ReinRaus: насколько я понимаю, просто ищется закрывающий `*/` без какой-либо интерпретации содержимого. то есть конструкция `/*\*/` должна быть валидным комментарием.

Comment: @VladD, осталось только переписать на С# :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: оставим это в качестве упражнения :)